# How not to click the sub <a> tags?

Tags: jquery, onclick, css-selectors

How can I click the first level of  tag only but not the other  tags embedded inside the first level?

For instance, this the html,

```
 <!-- tile-tag -->
<div class="tile-tag">

    <h3>tags</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">pr</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">interfaith</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">green</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">Tole-rants</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">media-training</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">public speaking</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">ethics</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">clients</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>&#43;</span><a href="#">people</a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>     
            <li><span>&#95;</span><a href="#">sub tag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</div>
<!-- tile-tag -->
```

the jquery,

```
$('.tile-tag a').click(function(){
        //alert($(this).text());

        // Set the variable.
        var parent_object = $(this).parent();
        var siblings_parent = parent_object.siblings();

        // Clean all siblings' style.
        siblings_parent.removeClass('current-tag');
        $('span:first',siblings_parent).html('&#43;');
        $('ul',siblings_parent).slideUp('fast');

        // Attach style to object's parent.
        parent_object.toggleClass('current-tag');
        $('ul',parent_object).slideToggle('fast');

        // Swap the object's parent's span html
        if(parent_object.hasClass('current-tag')) $('span:first',parent_object).html('&#150;');
        else $('span:first',parent_object).html('&#43;');

        return false;
    });
```

`$('.tile-tag a')` this will apply to all  tags including the sub  tags. but I don't this code apply to the sub  tags.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the ones in the first `ul`?

```
$('.tile-tag > ul > li > a')
```

See the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) API page and compare to the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).